# In cloudera 5.12 to what value is $HADOOP_HOME set?

Tags: hadoop, cloudera

My question is in `cloudera 5.12`; To what value is `$HADOOP_HOME` set?

Can someone help me on this?

Comment: Cloudera Manager should've already set this for you during installation...

Comment: Cricket_007 is correct, CM should set this.  If you have a look at the CM process in one of the HDFS or yarn services it should show it there.